# Получить содержимое тега

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Привет всем.
Изучаю регулярные выражения и столкнулся с такой проблемой. Нужно получить содержимое тега div, с учетом присутствия подобных тегов в данном содержимом, т.е. имеем следующее

```
<div>
    <div>
       <div class="parent">
          <div class="child">содержимое1</div>
          <div class="child">содержимое2</div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="child">содержимое3</div>
   <div class="child">содержимое4</div>
</div>
```

Нужно вытащить содержимое тега с классом parent. Пока удалось получить выражение следующего вида

```
/\<div class=\"parent\"\>(?:(?!\<\/div\>).)*\<\/div\>/s
```

но оно находит только первый child

Answer (score 1):

В твоём случае лучше всего подходит работа с XPath или селекторами JQuery.

```
XPath: [@class="parent"] -- Хотя я могу ошибиться, нужно читать информацию

JQuery: $('.parent') -- возвращает все ноды с аттрибутом class="parent"
```

Если ты хочешь регуляркой, то толькой одной ей не получится.
Нужно сначала найти открытие тега с нужным аттрибутом

```
|<div class="parent">|
```

После того как нашёл открытие тега нужно найти его закрытие по принципу поиска закрывающих скобок. По следующему алгоритму:

1. Инициализируешь счётчик i = 1, и строковый буффер res = ''
2. Если i = 0, то в res содержимое тега.
3. Идёшь по входной строке и находишь самое первое вхождение либо  а)`|<div.*?>|` либо б)`|</div>|` . При этом всё записываешь в буффер.
4. Если найденный элемент а. То увеличиваешь счётчик i на 1. Переходишь на пункт 3.
5. Если найденный элемент б. То уменьшаешь счётчик i на 1. Переходишь на пункт 2.

Answer (score 1):

можно попробовать что-нибудь типа "`<[*^>]+.classname[*^]+>`"
(возможно я с ошибкой написал, но суть такая: открытая_скобка + что_угодно_кроме_закрытой_скобки + название_класса + что_угодно_кроме_закрытой_скобки + закрытая_скобка

Answer (score 0):

Не силен в сложных регулярках, вот чего только смог добиться http://regex101.com/r/xP7bW1 Может кто-нибудь исправит или дополнит (если сам не докумекаю).

Comment: А я никак не могу до конца сообразить)) 
в принципе, ваш вариант устраивает. Спасибо!

Comment: Есть один весьма весомый недостаток на мой взгляд - оно не находит совпадений, если есть вложенные теги 2-го уровня. Пример:

    <div class="parent">
              <div class="child">содержимое1<div class="child">вложенное содержимое1</div></div>
              <div class="child">содержимое2</div>
    </div>

Comment: Сейчас потестировал с различными вариантами, действительно этот недостаток присутствует.